# How to get number of rows that displayed on a page on Vue Table

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, bootstrap-table

I'm doing a project using vue bootstrap and I need to get the number of rows displayed on a page. Let's say I have 24 data and I stored it on a table that use pagination. Each page will contain n rows where n is a dynamic number. How do I achieve "Showing n data from 24 data". I can't really find how because most of the example I found on the internet using data.length which return the length of data which is 24 meanwhile I need it to return n row of data that displayed on that page. I hope my explanation is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this link](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#v-model-binding).

You can bind to the currently displayed rows using `v-model` on the `b-table`, where you can find the length of currently displayed items.

You can also bind to the `filtered` [event](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#comp-ref-b-table-events) to find how many items are being shown in total (before pagination).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we are the only one who define the rows per page by using `:per-page` attribute on `<b-table>`. Hence, we already know what number we are passing as a value in `:per-page`.

Have a look in below live demo, You will get the idea **:**

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      perPage: 3,
      currentPage: 1,
      items: [
        { id: 1, first_name: 'Fred', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
        { id: 2, first_name: 'Wilma', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
        { id: 3, first_name: 'Barney', last_name: 'Rubble' },
        { id: 4, first_name: 'Betty', last_name: 'Rubble' },
        { id: 5, first_name: 'Pebbles', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
        { id: 6, first_name: 'Bamm Bamm', last_name: 'Rubble' },
        { id: 7, first_name: 'The Great', last_name: 'Gazzoo' },
        { id: 8, first_name: 'Rockhead', last_name: 'Slate' },
        { id: 9, first_name: 'Pearl', last_name: 'Slaghoople' }
      ]
    },
    computed: {
      rows() {
        return this.items.length
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<div id="app">
  <div class="overflow-auto">
    <b-pagination
                  v-model="currentPage"
                  :total-rows="rows"
                  :per-page="perPage"
                  aria-controls="my-table"
                  ></b-pagination>

    <p class="mt-3">Current Page: {{ currentPage }}</p>

    <b-table
             id="my-table"
             :items="items"
             :per-page="perPage"
             :current-page="currentPage"
             small
             ></b-table>
  </div>
</div>
```